# Angular ngx-translate usage in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm using this @ngx-translate/core i18n service and it works fine in templates (.html) with this syntax:

**{{'my.i18n.key'|translate}}**

Now I want to translate something in my component typescript file (.ts) but I don't know how to use it.

I can create translate object in my constructor:

**constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}**

and now how to translate 'my.i18n.key' ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the doc on [github](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods):

> get(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object):
>   Observable: Gets the translated value of a key (or an
>   array of keys) or the key if the value was not found

try in your controller/class:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    let foo:string = this.translate.get('myKey');
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Actually this returns translate object and I had to subscribe to get a string value like this: this.translate.get('my.i18n.key').subscribe(res => { console.log(res); });

Comment: That works like a charme. However, how can I check if there is a translateion, or it doesn't find any? When there's no translation for that key, it just returns that key in the observable, so I can't check the "success" of the translation

Comment: better ```constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    let foo:string = this.translate.stream('myKey');
}```

Comment: @netalex Subscribing to `stream` worked for me to update text in real time on language change, while `instant` and subscription to `get` would only trigger once.

Answer (score 107):

To translate something in your typescript file, do the following

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}
```

then use like this wherever you need to translate

```
this.translate.instant('my.i18n.key')
```

Comment: this will return the translated string from the en.json (your language) file

Comment: should be this the correct answer... from doc `/**
     * Returns a translation instantly from the internal state of loaded translation.
     * All rules regarding the current language, the preferred language of even fallback languages will be used except any promise handling.
     */`

Comment: I am not sure, bit "instant" works only when the resource content is loaded, if instant is called before the loading of translation resources is finishe (ngOnIt - for example) it returns only the path to the resource.

Comment: Thank you, Friend! The solution is really simple and usable!

Answer (score 9):

To translate in Typscript file ,do follow code

Import in header

```
 import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

In constructor declare as

```
public translate: TranslateService
```

Suppose the JSON file looks like this

```
{
    "menu":{
        "Home": "Accueil"
            }
}
```

Declare the below code in constructor.

Note: Key stands for your main key value that used in language.json file (Here it is "menu")

```
 this.translate.get('menu').subscribe((data:any)=> {
       console.log(data);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

also, if you want 'menu.Home' value directly ...you can get it by 

this.translate.instant('menu.Home'));

Comment: does it work for nested objects tho? it doesnt for me

Answer (score 5):

I am using angular 8 > In my case > If you want to translate typescript string into another language then use this >
First, make a service file to get translate value, Below is my code for globaltranslate.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {}
```

Then make a return function........

```
getTranslation(str) {
    const currentLang = this.translate.currentLang; // get current language
    const returnValue = this.translate.translations[currentLang][str]; // get converted string from current language
    if (returnValue === undefined) {
      return this.translate.translations.en_merch[str]; // if value is getting undefined then return default language string, en_merch is default english language file here
    } else {
      return returnValue;
    }
  }
```

And in component.ts file, you can import service file and use it like below code...

```
import {GlobaltranslateService} from '../../../../services/globaltranslate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [GlobaltranslateService]   // add service in provider
})

constructor(
      private gTranslate: GlobaltranslateService // add service into constructor
  ) {}

const title = this.gTranslate.getTranslation('Title text'); // get return value by calling function 'getTranslation' in globaltranslateservice.
```

This solution is better for all projects of **i18n** and **angular** **ngx translate**

This also works on **sweetalert2 strings like below code**

```
Swal (
   this.gTranslate.getTranslation('Warning'),
   data.message,
   'warning'
);
```

Thanks for reading, If you have any query please message.

Comment: What if the translation key has multiple levels like 'USER.PROFILE.NAME' at that time the above code breaks

Comment: For that you can use lodash get property which will handle the above case
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Answer (score 4):

You can use translate.instant() method and pass the key name which is stored in your i18n file. for example:

```
translate.instant('hello');
```

and If that's coming from a parameter or variable, directly pass the value.

```js
translate.instant(my.i18n.key);
```

You can also refer to this ans:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/835#issuecomment-384188498

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the problem is when this was posted, but assigning the "get" method to a variable in order to get the translated string won't work, as it returns an observable

get should be used like this:

```js
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }
   :
   :
this.translate.get ('KEY_TO_TRANSLATE').subscribe (x=> this.translation = x);
```

To get the string you can use the Instant method:

```js
this.translation = this.translate.instant('KEY_TO_TRANSLATE')
```

However, this is a synchronous method, so if the translation has not loaded yet, you 'll get the key, not the value. It's all explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) that can be found in Github.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me ( i am using Angular 7).
Just import the Translate service on the constructor and then call it from inside myfunction like this :

```
  getTranslation(){
    let translation = "";
    let clientTranslation = this.translate.get('auth.client').subscribe(cliente =>{
        translation = cliente;
        document.getElementById("clientTest").setAttribute('value', translation);
    }
}
```

I was using the translation on a form so i pass it to the input with 
   setAttribute, hope this example could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
errorMessage:string="";
constructor(
    protected translate:TranslateService,
  
  ) {   

}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
   this.translate.get('PLEASE_ENTER_OTP').subscribe(data=>{
      this.errorMessage=data;
    })
  }
```

You can subscribe the observable in `ngOninit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translate.stream and it will change the value according to the language changes.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
 this.translate
  .stream('my.i18n.key')
  .subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Refer https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods for more explanation.