# How can I use ngx-translateservice to translate method in typescript

Tags: typescript, ngx-translate

I have tried to solve my task with all of these examples in this question [Angular ngx-translate usage in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870513/angular-ngx-translate-usage-in-typescript) I do not know how to connect TranslateService to my method.

Swedish translation file `se.json` (without key)

```
{
    NAME: Namn
}
```

English translation file `en.json` (without key)

```
{
    NAME: Name
}
```

typescript:

import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

```
constructor {
 private translate: TranslateService
} {
    this.translate.use(localStorage.getItem("language")); // Get selected language
}
```

Method that I want to translate:

```
setColumns(): void {
  this.loggedInUserType = Meteor.user().profile.user_type;
  if (this.type === "history") {
    this.columns = [
      { header: "NAME" },
      { header: "TOTALSUM" },
      { header: "VAT" },
      { header: "INVOICES" },
    ];
  } else if (this.type === "clients") {
    this.columns = [
      { header: "NAME" },
      { header: "ORGANIZATIONNUMBER" },
      { header: "CITY" },
      { header: "COUNTRY" },
      { header: "ACTIONS" },
   ];
    this.getClients();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. app.module.ts

   ```
   export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
     return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
   }

   export class TranslateHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
     handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
       /* some logic */
     }
   }

   export function appInitializerFactory(translateService: TranslateService, injector: Injector): () => Promise<any> {
     // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
     return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
       const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
       locationInitialized.then(() => {
         translateService.use(localStorage.getItem("language") || window.navigator.language) // here u can change language loaded before reander enything
           .pipe(take(1))
           .subscribe(() => {},
           err => console.error(err), () => resolve(null));
       });
     });
   }

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           ...,
           TranslateModule.forRoot({
               loader: {
                   provide: TranslateLoader,
                   useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                   deps: [HttpClient]
               },
               isolate: false,
               missingTranslationHandler: [{provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslateHandler}]
           }),
       ]
       providers: [
           ...,
           {
               provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
               useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
               deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
               multi: true
           }
       ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
2. in module of your component add `TranslationModule`
3. in component constructor `public ts: TranslateService) {}`
4. now u can use:

   ```
   this.ts.instant('YOUR_KEY'); // return translated string or your key if translation not founded, but u can change logic in TranslateHandler
   ```
5. all translations stored in **assets/i18n/**. for example **en.json**