# translate on .ts File on Angular @ngx-translate

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, transactions, ngx-translate

I am working on a meteor-Angular project, where I am using `@ngx-translate` for translation.

Now when it comes to `HTML` files the translation works perfectly fine with a translation JSON file.

But when it comes to the ts file I do not know how to translate the words. Here is an example -

[image]

I have tried a lot how to translate `.ts file` but somehow I couldn't find a single solution to this problem. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `instant` method in the component.

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

```
 this.column : [
    {header : this.translate.instant('ACCOUNT_TYPE')},
    {header : this.translate.instant('NAME')},
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can look my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67633615/7103430)

for currect working after f5 u need to use appInitializerFactory (don't forgot add it to providers like in answer)

Answer (score 0):

you should translate when sending to HTML whit the pipe.

If the column is a FOR, also for each word use the pipe. ( column[0] | translate)