# react-native not showing translated text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization, react-i18next

I have the following tree structure

```
❯ tree src/localization 
src/localization
├── en
│   └── index.ts
├── i18n.ts
└── ta
    └── index.ts
```

and the following i18n.ts file contents

```
❯ cat src/localization/i18n.ts 
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import en from "./en/index";
import ta from "./ta/index";

const resources = {
  // list of languages
  en,
  ta,
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: "v3",
  resources,
  lng: "ta", // default language to use.
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

And I include this `i18n.ts` in my `App.tsx` as below:

```
❯ cat App.tsx 
import { AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext";
import { AppNav } from "./src/context/AppNav";
import "./src/localization/i18n";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <AppNav />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now I try to use a translation from the above file in a react-native screen, like below:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const { t } = useTranslation();
<Text> {t("sign_in")} </Text>
```

In the `ta/index.ts` and the `en/index.ts` I have no namespace and have translated strings. But in the `npm run web` on the browser, the `sign_in` text appears as is, instead of the translated string from the localization directory. I tried changing the default language to `en` also and set a different value for the sign_in key and even that does not help. The content of `ta/index.ts` is as below:

```
export default {
  account_handle: "பயனர் கணக்கு",
  change_language: "Change Language",
  forgot_password: "கடவுச்சொல் மறந்ததோ",
  password: "கடவுச்சொல்",
  sign_in: "உள்ளே போ",
};
```

The entire react-native project is available at: https://github.com/psankar/immiapp/tree/e87ca8a9b4de764608da96d2945120383f50ed70

The react-component where I am trying to use the translated string is: https://github.com/psankar/immiapp/blob/e87ca8a9b4de764608da96d2945120383f50ed70/src/screens/SignIn.tsx#L114

What am I doing wrong that the translated strings are not appearing in the UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make changes to the i18n.ts as below by adding a `translation` key:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: "v3",
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: en,
    },
    ta: {
      translation: ta,
    },
  },
  lng: "ta", // default language to use.
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});
```

and in the SignIn.tsx, had to import the `t` function via the above file, such as:

```
import i18n from "../localization/i18n";
<Text>{i18n.t("sign_in")}</Text>
```

Comment: My answer to similar in typescript. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50754530/3417228 -Kumar S